# Could the order of a list contained in a dictionary vary?

Tags: python

It is known that dictionaries may be sorted in a different order that the one which each key,value pair is inserted.

For example :
    my_dict = {}

```
my_dict.update({'A': 2})
my_dict.update({'B': 1})

for keys,values in my_dict.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)
#may result in
B        A
1   or   2
A        B
2        1
```

Then, is an object, contained in a dictionnary may encounter the same behaviour ?

For illustration :

```
another_dict = {'Type A': [4], 'Type B' : [0]}

another_dict['Type A'].append(2)
another_dict['Type B'].append(1)

for keys,values in another_dict.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)

Type A: 4, 2 
Type B: 0, 1
```

Will the content of the lists remain in the same order than their insertion, despite the lists order may vary ?

Comment: lists preserve insertion order, dicts unless you're using python `3.7` or `OrderedDict`s don't

Comment: Lists are ordered period, it doesn't matter if they are nested inside some other unordered structures

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong. The first snippet will always output `Nb 1`, never `Nb 2`. Also, the 2nd snippet will output `Type A` `[4, 2, 1]` `Type B` `[0]`. Never anything else.

Comment: @EdChum If I understood correctly,in case I got multiple lists, the content of each one will remain in the same order, but their order may vary, right?

Comment: Your lists will preserve insertion order, the dict keys will not unless you're using `3.7` python or an `OrderedDict`

Comment: @Aran-Fey You're right, I'll fix it.

Comment: The values are your responsibility, the order of keys are the dict's responsibility.

Comment: Thanks @all for your help. I don't know the way to mark the question as answered as there is only comments, should I post an answer or wait for a comment author to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by multiple people in the comments, only the order of the keys may vary, not the values.

```
#In python versions prior to 3.7
another_dict = {'Type A': [4], 'Type B' : [0]}

another_dict['Type A'].append(2)
another_dict['Type B'].append(1)

for keys,values in another_dict.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)

#May occur in
'Type A': [4, 2]
'Type B': [0, 1]
#or              #Lists content order will remain the same in both cases, no matter the version you use
'Type B': [0, 1]
'Type A': [4, 2]
```

Also, as said by @EdChum, please note that the unsorting behaviour shown in the first case won't occur if you use Python 3.7+, or the specific OrderedDict class for older versions.